how to locate the reason udp out of order in send device?
I'm using rk3588 device transfer some data to a device whice connected with a phy, and the device receive data out of order, like pack 0 pack 2 pack 1. But i'm sure i send it with 0 1 2 order with 1 thread, so i use tcpdump to locate where the data went wrong, and i found the data in tcpdump already out of order in the device, so the problem isn't udp it self(i think), buf in the device.
i tried
enlarge the mem like sysctl -w net.core.wmem_default=33554423
sysctl -w net.core.wmem_max=33554423
ethtool -K eth tso off gso off tx off,
it doesn't work.The dmesg looks everthing good, i want to locate the problem and solve(if there is any way),at least to localte the problem.
According to the research, lots of people suggest to use tcp, and add seq in my data, however it's not possible to switch protocol in a mature product, and i already add seq. But my leader  ask me to find out the reason, not just avoid the problem. I have no idear, help me.
The device receive outof order is acceptable, but in the rk3588 itself the package out of order is abnormal.
there is the main stracture of the send function:
    while (rate < 100)
    {
        memset(&st_read_restult.arr_pic_data, 0, sizeof(st_read_restult.arr_pic_data));
        st_read_restult.pic_data_index = 0;
        n_ret = st_sdk_bkg_dma_process.read_file_buf(&st_read_in, &st_read_restult);
        
        LOG_DEBUG(LOG_PICTURE, "n_picture_id [%d] en_file_type [%d] arr_file_path[%s] n_effective_num [%d]", g_st_bkg_tmp.n_picture_id, g_st_bkg_tmp.en_file_type, \
                g_st_bkg_tmp.arr_file_path, n_effective_num);
        //calculate package num
        n_op_cnt = 0;
        n_write_start = 0;
        n_effective_num = (st_read_restult.pic_data_index % PICTURE_DMA_WRITE_LEN) ? (st_read_restult.pic_data_index / PICTURE_DMA_WRITE_LEN + 1) : st_read_restult.pic_data_index / PICTURE_DMA_WRITE_LEN;

        for (i = 0; i < n_effective_num; i++)
        {
            bkg_write_t st_bkg_write = {0};
            //assign seq
            st_read_restult.n_pack_seq = n_pack_seq++;
            st_bkg_write.arr_pic_data = st_read_restult.arr_pic_data;
            st_bkg_write.n_write_start = n_write_start;
            st_bkg_write.n_bkg_data_len = (n_write_start + PICTURE_DMA_WRITE_LEN > st_read_restult.pic_data_index) ? (st_read_restult.pic_data_index - n_write_start) : PICTURE_DMA_WRITE_LEN;
            n_write_start += st_bkg_write.n_bkg_data_len;


            LOG_DEBUG(LOG_PICTURE,"start send dma[%d]", j);
            p_bkg_data_op[n_op_cnt] = NULL;
            SDK_MEM_ALLOC(p_bkg_data_op[n_op_cnt], sizeof(transfer_op_t), (transfer_op_t *)malloc, LOG_PICTURE, &n_ret, SDK_RET_MEM_OVER);
            n_ret = st_sdk_bkg_dma_process.dma_write_func_0(&st_bkg_write, p_index[j], p_bkg_data_op[n_op_cnt]);//send called finally
            n_op_cnt++;
            SDK_RET_CHECK(n_ret, LOG_PICTURE);
            // usleep(20);//add this sleep can slove out of oder problem
        }
    }
       

this is tcpdump result of my seq in the package

Wikipedia tells about UDP: "there is no guarantee of delivery, ordering, or duplicate protection." The order can be changed by the transmitter, by any intermediate station and by the receiver. It is the responsibility of the applications to reorder the packets.

Your network interface will likely have multiple transmission queues (most modern NICs do), and depending on which traffic shaping queuing discipline you have set up, the UDP packages you generate will likely be put into different queues depending on the fill state of each queue -- which can then cause packet reordering. (The default mqprio tc qdisc will do that, for example.)
You have a couple of options:

You can choose a queuing discipline that always sorts the UDP packets you generate into the same queue (but may sort other packets into different queues). The traffic shaping infrastructure is quite complicated to understand though.

You can use ethtool --set-channels ethXYZ tx 1 (or ethtool --set-channels ethXYZ combined 1 if your NIC driver doesn't support configuring tx/rx separately) to force that your NIC only uses a single transmission queue (systemd-networkd also exposes this as the TxChannels=/CombinedChannels= configuration option for *.link files). This may have performance / CPU usage distribution disadvantages, especially for fast NICs. (And especially if you have to use that for combined channels, which will also affect your receive queue.)

You can live with the fact that the multiple transmission queues in your NIC cause the network packets to be reordered.



This does not help if the reordering occurs during the transmission of the packets in the middle of the route. For example, the route itself could change.

@Wiimm Sure, but the question was specifically about the order in which the packets are sent out by the system, not about the order in which they were received.

i think so, buf my leader ask me to find out the reason, i have to do this...QAQ

thank you chris, i tried ethtool --set-channels eth10 tx 1 and add it to start task, after boot,  ethtool -l eth10 showsChannel parameters for eth10:
Pre-set maximums:
RX:             2
TX:             2
Other:          0
Combined:       0
Current hardware settings:
RX:             2
TX:             1
Other:          0
Combined:       0
but the problem still exists.... thanks anyway.

@user28690465 If that doesn't fix it, you need to provide more information about how you actually send data. The code you posted uses library functions that are probably internal to your codebase, for which there is no public information available. At the very least you could try to strace your sending program and see what system calls it makes to actually send the data. Also, your code example mentions DMA a couple of times, so are you per chance talking low-level with the network hardware and not via the kernel?

@chris_se sorry for not reply, i'm toooooo busy this days, and i tried strace as you mentioned, the result is show in below. Sincerely thanks your help.

i used strace,the result as show in below:
the first pic. is strace at about 00 20(little enidan, means 0x2000 and should followed by 0120 0220 0320 0420),the result is as expected.

and this is tcpdump result in wireshark, as you can see, bytes from 0x48 is the package seq. package 8218 seq = 0x2001 package 8219 = 0x2004 and package 8220 = 0x2002 ...20003 2005... and so on. it doesn't compare with the seq. in strace. it you need the raw tcpdump data and strace txt i can post it.




As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
